# Trying to make a JSON POST request to the TVDB REST API at https://api.thetvdb.com/, but getting CORS error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, rest, cors

I am porting an application from Django to purely HTML5/CSS with AngularJS and am facing issues making JSON POST requests to TheTVDB REST API server (https://api.thetvdb.com/).

The API call is being done in a service on AngularJS:

```
return {
    login: function(){
        return $http({
            method: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            data: {'apikey':apiKey, 'username': username, 'userkey': identifier},
            url: tvdbAuthURL
        })
    }
}
```

And then I get this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.thetvdb.com/login/. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.
```

I have tried avoiding pre-flighting the request but no luck and since I did not have this issue using python requests lib, for example, (I trigger request to the tvDB using this python lib from the same machine running the angular JS app with no problems at all) I wonder if there isn't a way or a different directive in AngularJS to keep it from setting CORS headers.

TheTVDB will not add CORS to their server as most of their users are running Laravel (PHP), Java and Django(Python) applications and are using their services with no such CORS problems.

Your help is much appreciated.

Thank you,
Best Regards
TS

Comment: Create a proxy in python

Comment: I wanted to avoid that for architectural reasons. But does that mean that I am limited by AngularJS for when servers do not provide CORS support?

Comment: No it means you are limited by browser security. You have no other choice other than use a third party proxy

Comment: your api receives data from the body? or via parameters?, also isn't reduntant use dataType with the headers?

Comment: @PauloGaldoSandoval I would receive a json back from the server with the token information for me to carry on with other requests. The dataType maybe redundant, but it is not of an impact here, I suppose.

Comment: Some answers may be here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work

Something else not suggested here other than proxy is to Embed the remote server in an iframe and communicate through fragment or window.name, check this out http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-crossdomaincomm/#N10120

Comment: @applecrusher thank you! I am very eager to try the iframe solution and see how that goes about! That is a very interesting work around and clean from my perspective and which to keep it a stand alone application with fewer dependencies as possible. I will give it a try and let you all know how that goes!

Answer (score 1):

Your Python request works because it is coming from your server or local machine, and the [same origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) only applies inside a browser.

Your best answer is to use a server-side script. Have your client side POST request go to a controller or endpoint on your server, which then triggers the server script. Assuming there is some return data from the API, you'd add that to your server's response and then send it to the client.

Comment: My python request is triggered from localhost, my machine, to https://api.thetvdb.com/, so not from the server. I have no access to the server whatsoever, so I would have to have a python layer sitting on the same side as my angularJs just to intermediate these requests, as per the other comments and suggestions on this thread which I would like to avoid as much as possible.

Comment: Sorry, I guess my answer was a little muddled. In this case, when I say "the server" I mean your local machine, or anywhere you are hosting your backend code. The API would be the server you have no control over.

That's assuming you ARE hosting backend code somewhere. If this program is client-only and the API isn't CORS compliant, you're boned on a POST action.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look here: https://forums.thetvdb.com/viewtopic.php?t=9125

The TVdb doesn't provide any cors header, which means you can't access the API directly via Javascript. However, as @Matt West said, the cors policy only works in browsers.
The quick solution: Create a python program as a proxy, which redirect all your AJAX request to TVdb.

Answer (score 0):

Use a JSONP request. That way you can dodge the CORS.

EDIT: sorry, you're using POST, this would only work for get requests.

You can create a proxy that receives the request and then makes a CURL POST. There is no server side 'CORS' so you will be ok.

Comment: Can't just say use jsonp as if it's  magic fix for all CORS. API has to support it

Comment: Actually I can't use JSONP as I am actually issuing a POST request and I understant JSONP is for GET only, right?